# bootstrap datepicker - change background color from yellow to blue

Tags: bootstrap-4, datepicker

for a bootstrap datepicker, when set the "todayHighlight" property as true, it opens with current day highlighted as yellow.
can we change this color, to blue or some other color.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the [demo](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=true&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&todayHighlight=on&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox). You will see that the styles are defined in https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css as below:

```
.datepicker table tr td.today {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ffdb99;
    border-color: #ffb733;
}
```

So you should just be able to override that in your css file, or an embedded stylesheet  loaded after bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css. Just use the same, or more specific selector and set as you whish:

```
.datepicker table tr td.today {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #009;
  border-color: blue;
}

/* or more specific */
.your-custom-class .datepicker table tr td.today {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #009;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thank you @ArleighHix for the help. i tried your suggested code above as - .                 
                                                                                                                                
 datepicker table tr td.today {
            color: rgb(194, 47, 47);
            background-color: rgb(153, 0, 0);
            border-color: blue;
        }    . the text color did change, but the background-color and border-color, still remained unchanged.

Comment: i even tried -   background-color: rgb(153, 0, 0) !important;

Comment: You must have some other styles loading after that, try the more specific selector using `your-custom-class` on the containing element

Comment: my html code is bare minimum - <div class='container'>
        <div class="row">
            <h2>Bootstrap DatePicker</h2>
            <hr />
            <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                <div class="inner-addon right-addon" id="divInput">
    
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" id="iconCal"></i>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtInput" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: which element would be the containing one.

Comment: thanks @ArleighHix for the immediate reply -- will try this weekend.

Comment: how do you add datepicker style to body tag - body {
    padding: 10px !important;
    .datepicker table tr td.today {
        color: rgb(194, 47, 47);
        background-color: rgb(153, 0, 0) !important;
        border-color: blue;
    }
} . probably that doesnt work.

Comment: `body.your-custom-class .datepicker table tr td.today{...}` and use `<body class="your-custom-class">`